# Remove a tag and content of it by substring and indexof in javascript

Tags: javascript, substring, indexof

i want to convert this:

```
<html>
s
<RB:Block_Left>sss</RB:Block_Left>
s
hello
</html>
```

to this,

```
<html>
s
s
hello
</html>
```

and this code must be in the textarea like this i made it but cant work!

```
<textarea id ="code">
<html>
s
<RB:Block_Left>sss</RB:Block_Left>
s
hello
</html>
</textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" value="makeit!" onclick="ARAS()" />
<br />
<textarea id ="newcode">
</textarea>
<script>
function ARAS(){
    str=document.getElementById('code').value;
    str=str.substring(  + str.indexOf('<html>') - str.indexOf('<\/RB:Block_Left>') + str.indexOf('<\/RB:Block_Left>'));
    document.getElementById('newcode').value=str;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your line :

```
str=str.substring(  + str.indexOf('<html>') - str.indexOf('<\/RB:Block_Left>') + str.indexOf('<\/RB:Block_Left>'));
```

with this line:

```
str=str.substring(0,str.indexOf("<RB")-1) + str.substring(str.indexOf("/RB")+15)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as with HTML elements and use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```javascript
var ta = $("#code"); // Textarea
var tag = 'tag'; // Tag name or selector you want to remove

ta.val(
  $("<div>" + ta.val() + "</div>") // Wrap content of the textarea into a DIV tag
    .find(tag) // Find all the tags you want to remove
    .remove() // Remove them
    .end() // Get back the parent element
    .html() // Get HTML of the element
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w7Rkm/